# How to create a custom widget using TFS data?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, azure-devops-rest-api

I would like to know if it is possible to create a custom TFS widget using data from my TFS Queries. The idea is to create a widget with a table where I will show the projects and the progress of the tasks involved for each one.
I already have a query that brings to me this info, but I don't know if it is possible to build the HTML table and populate it with this query data.

Comment: What version of TFS are you using?

Comment: It is 2015 (Version 14.102.25423.0)

Comment: That's TFS 2015  update 3, which supports extensions as recommended by @Toomaja.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to create a dashboard widget by creating a Team Foundation Server Extension. In the top right corner of your TFS web portal, you should see a button that allows you to browse extensions:

[image: Browse for extensions]

From here, you can access links for developing extensions or searching the marketplace for extensions:

- [Develop Extensions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/overview)
- [Marketplace for Extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/)

I recommend searching the marketplace for tag: "Dashboard Widgets" to see examples of custom TFS widgets.